# Adding Checkbox Form Fields via Ajax response to Rails Form, Not showing in params on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

First question asked here so hope I make the problem clear enough.

So I have this long rails form and am trying to cut down on load times and want to asynchronously add some checkboxes to my form from an AJAX response.  I get the checkboxes to render appropriately but the values are not coming through to the controller on the form submit.  I have tried several different options to no avail, so am looking for some guidance.  Fairly new to Rails, so thats part of it.

Here is some code:

```
function fetchCodes(){
  if (window.location.pathname.includes("/something")){
    $.ajax({
      url: '/codes',
      success: function(response){
        updateFields(response)
      },
      error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        throw new Error('ajax error: ' + $(JSON.stringify(error)));
      },
    });
  }
}
function updateFields(response){
  var select_option_core_business = $(".codes");
  var selected_options = response.data.selected_options

  console.log(selected_options)
  $.each(response.data.options, function(key, value) {
    select_option_core_business
        .append($('<div class="col-lg-12"><input type="checkbox" name="registration_form[core_business][]" value=' + value + '><label for="registration_form_core_business">' + value + '</label></div>'));
}
```

So after some time, the checkboxes appear on the DOM just as if they were rendered using my initial method:

```
<% codes.each do |segment| %>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
       <%= check_box_tag(
             'registration_form[core_business][]',
             segment,
             @registration_form.core_business.include?(segment),
             class: 'form-check-label'
           )%>
           <small><%= f.label :core_business, segment, class: 'form-check-label' %></small>
       </div>
 <% end %>
```

But when I submit the form, core_business does not come through in the params.  My thoughts are that the form doesn't recognize the newly added checkboxes since they were loaded asynchronously, but I can't be certain.  Has anyone else tried to do this?  I have tried appending in different ways with the same outcome, but only using jQuery methods.

Here is how it appears on the DOM:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <input type="checkbox" name="registration_form[core_business][]" value="Some Value" class="form-check-label" id="nil">
  <small class="pl-1">
   <label for="registration_form_core_business" class="form-check- 
    label">Some Value</label>
  </small>
</div>
```

Which matches how rails form helper outputs the html

Hoping someone has run into this before.  Thank you for your time!

Comment: Are you sure that the checkboxes are rendering _inside_ the form?

Comment: They are rendering in the same location as the one generated from the rails view so I would assume so